# Opportunity reporting in salesforce along with role hierarchy

Tags: reporting

Role Hierarchy:

CEO->VP->Sales Directors->Regional manager.

If opportunities are always owned by regional managers, can we  aggregate at the sales director level in standard reporting without using any customization to determine the sales director?

Comment: determine the sales director - what do you mean